# When "If you have any questions" refers to the future, why isn't it "if you would have any questions"?

Tags: tense, idiomatic-language, future-time

There are several questions here on ELL that refer to the idiom *"if you have any questions"*, but none of them touches upon why is it *"you have"* and not *"you **would** have"*, when that sentence refers to the future.

As an example:

> Teacher: Please finish this task until next Sunday.
> Student: No problem. If I (would) have any questions, I'll ask you by email.

Is the student in this example correctly using *would*?
If not, why is it? Assuming the student doesn't have questions now, and would only have questions once they start working on the task, shouldn't there be a *would*?

Related:

- [If I had/have any questions, I'll ask](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/281848/if-i-had-have-any-questions-ill-ask)
- [If you have any question(s)](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/194284/if-you-have-any-questions)
- [If you have (any) questions](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/191021/if-you-have-any-questions)
- [“If I have some questions I will write you”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90613/if-i-have-some-questions-i-will-write-you)

Comment: Much more natural, surely, would be to say, "If I do have any questions..."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's one of those peculiar grammatical aspects of the language we learners have to adjust our brains to. In English, present tenses (the simple in particular) are usually used to refer to the future:

- in time clauses with *when, after, before, by the time, until, as soon as*:

  - *When* you **see** her, tell her ...
  - I should be finished *by the time* you **get** back.
- in conditional clauses with *if, unless, in case, provided*:

  - *Provided* he **is** available...
  - I'll bring some food *in case* we **don't find** anywhere decent to eat.
- *what if* and *suppose* clauses

  - What if the train **is**/was late?
  - Suppose we **miss**/missed the bus.

Comment: Thank you! you say that present tenses are usually used. Can future tenses also be used? if they can, would a native speaker usually choose the present tense in such cases?

Comment: @HeyJude, edited it to "are usually used" to stress that normally futures tenses are not used in such clauses

Comment: @HeyJude Have a look https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/301323/if-you-will-have-vs-if-you-have, but it's rather an old-fashioned "abnormality"

Comment: @HeyJude Another slightly related topic https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/451800/usage-of-if-you-would touches on the correctness of "If you would"

Comment: I would not say that _present tenses (the simple in particular) are usually used to refer to the future_, They can be used, but that is not how they are normally used. If a person says _I am here_, that doesn't mean _I will be here_.

Comment: @kiamlaluno The sentence doesn't end there, that colon is misleading... *"... are usually used to refer to the future in time/conditional clauses ..."*

Answer (score 1):

There actually is a similar construction in one translation (the New International Version) of Isaiah 21:12. But it’s that way for complicated reasons.

> Morning is coming, but also the night.
> If you would ask, then ask;
>          and come back yet again.

In modern English, “If you would” reads to me as a slightly-quaint way of expressing, “If you want to,” and not the future tense.  In this particular instance, “If you would ask” is a translation of the Hebrew אִם־תִּבְעָי֥וּן, which is in the imperfect rather than the future tense, so the translators probably chose a construction that was not the usual future tense.

Anyway, “If you would ask,” is not the normal way to say it, and I wouldn’t recommend you imitate that example.  But if you like the sound of it, you might quote the literary passage!